# How to import tested modules in tests?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-import

I am new at Python and coming from Java background.

Suppose I am developing a Python project with package `hello`:

```
hello_python/
  hello/
    hello.py
    __init__.py
  test/
    test_hello1.py
    test_hello2.py
```

I believe the project structure is correct.

Suppose `hello.py` contains function `do_hello()` I want to use in tests. How to import `do_hello` in tests `test_hello1.py` and `test_hello2.py` ?

Comment: Importing in tests is no different from importing in any other code. In your case you would do `from hello.hello import do_hello`.

Comment: Thanks. I got it. Now the tests are running Ok in `PyCharm`. However when I run a test in command line `python -m unittest test_hello_server` in current directory `test` I got `ImportError: No module named hello_server.hello_server`.

Comment: Because the parent directory wouldn't be on the pythonpath. Rather, you should start from inside `hello_python`, and do `python -m unittest test.test_hello` or whatever.

Comment: Tried it now. Got `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test_hello'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've 2 small issues here. Firstly, you're running your test command from the wrong directory, and secondly you've not quite structured your project right.

Usually when I'm developing a python project I try to keep everything focussed around the project's root, which would be `hello_python/` in your case. Python has the current working directory on its load path by default, so if you've got a project like this:

```
hello_python/
  hello/
    hello.py
    __init__.py
  test/
    test_hello1.py
    test_hello2.py


# hello/hello.py
def do_hello():
    return 'hello'

# test/test_hello.py
import unittest2
from hello.hello import do_hello

class HelloTest(unittest2.TestCase):
    def test_hello(self):
        self.assertEqual(do_hello(), 'hello')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest2.main()
```

Second, `test` isn't a module right now, since you've missed the `__init__.py` in that directory. You should have a hierarchy that looks like this:

```
hello_python/
  hello/
    hello.py
    __init__.py
  test/
    __init__.py    #  <= This is what you were missing
    test_hello1.py
    test_hello2.py
```

When I try that on my machine, running `python -m unittest test.hello_test` works fine for me.

You may find that this is still a bit cumbersome. I'd strongly recommend installing [nose](http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which will let you simply invoke `nosetests` from your project's root to find and execute all your tests automagically - providing you've got correct modules with `__init__.py`s.

Comment: Just noticed that you run `python` with `-m` switch. It works for me now ! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your example has a small issue. When I execute the unit test _no test_ actually runs because test method `hello_test` doesn't start with `test`. instances of `TestCase` run only methods `test_*` as their tests by convention.

Comment: @Michael Whoops! Serves me right for transcribing everything by hand rather than copy-pasting.